# Keep leading whitespace inside a dropdown menu

Tags: html

I'm trying to write a drop down menu with subheadings, where the options within the subheadings are indented. However the indentation is constantly lost.

This is a sample of code:

```
<optgroup class="mrMultiple" label="CONSUMER" style=""></optgroup><option class="mrMultiple" value="SALES" style="">
          SALES
    </option><option class="mrMultiple" value="Promotion" style="">
          MARKETING PROMOTION
    </option><option class="mrMultiple" value="MONEYVISTA" style="">
          MONEYVISTA
    </option>
```

As a note, I've tried both `&nbsp;` and `<pre></pre>`. The latter does nothing and the former just shows `&nbsp;` in it's literal form.

Because of how my work generates these websites I can only change the inner HTML and not the attributes/elements. However inside the inner HTML I can do whatever.

Edit:

Just for completeness. This was never solved and has been accepted as a fact of life for the language that was being used, a pretty disappointing fact as well.

Comment: ``&nbsp;`` really should work. Are you sure you're not doing any html encoding for the text content of the options?

Comment: @Kippie, what do you mean? Sorry as I said I'm not great at HTML and almost all of it is generated for me using a higher-level language.

Comment: Thinking about the &nbsp; - It's probably how my other programme generates the HTML that does it.

Comment: @Scironic What `higher-level language` is that? Does that generate this HTML for you or are you manually creating this?

Comment: It's not a common one. MRScriptBasic. it's specific to market research. And yes it generates almost all the HTML, the CSS and JS can be edited by me but only if budgeted, otherwise we use a template which is what I've got for this job.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to use css. If you can't do that you could wrap you text in a tag (like a span for instance). then you could add inline css to that.

Comment: Can't use CSS (time and budget constraints) it has to be done with the inner html. Although I can do divs, lists etc within that. What inline css would maintain the whitespace?

Comment: then change the innerhtml to something similar to this:
<option class="mrMultiple" value="Promotion" style="">
        <span style="padding-left:5px;">  MARKETING PROMOTION</span>
    </option>

Comment: This is ridiculous. For any other part of the page I would be able to do this. But in the dropdown list if you add any html tags as such to the inner html it is all deleted. - odd but frustrating. I think this will be a fruitless endeavour.

Comment: And why is it to difficult to add css? you could fix this with something like this:
optgroup option{padding-left:5px;} 
I noticed you use the same class for the optgroup and the options. Perhaps the css for the class has something to do with the whitespace issue??

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I checked out the CSS and most of it covers font-family, color, size and line-height. The only thing that may be affecting it is an inherited "text-align: left;" Inline css I can do, not through an external file though. It's more to the point that again, I'm not very good at it. as for the padding, I put it into the span option and it didn't work. this is only for some options, those under subheadings, not all of them.

Comment: have you tried adding the padding-left style to the option tag itself?
like <opton .... style="padding-left:5px;">...</option>

Comment: I can't edit the tag as I'm using a higher level language to generate the html. the first time I get to see it is when it's in the browser

Comment: Which language are you using? Can you post the code? Can you not add an external css file because of this code of because you don't know how? (because we could show you how...)

Comment: Sorry about coming back to this so late. I use a language called MRScriptBasic which is specialised for market research. I already have external CSS files which we use and I know how to add and modify, but we would only be able to change the option class which would not work for what we're trying to do (change only a select few options). I could theoretically import a js file which gave these options a class which then applied CSS but that would take too long.